# Can't see code (every function and class block shows 3 dots ) in django modules when open with ctrl+click in vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Cnx.png)

i try to uninstall and reinstall vscode and also try different python version(3.8 & 3.6) interpreter
can't fix my issue

Comment: click on that three dot and you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a stub file(**.pyi**) instead of the resource code.

[image]